# Prove $f(x)\sin x+f'(x)\cos x=1$

Tags: calculus

Let f be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f''(x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ are real. 
Suppose that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$

i) Prove that  $f(x)\sin x + f'(x)\cos x = 1$ for all $x$ are real.

ii) Prove that $f(x)\cos x - f'(x)\sin x = 0$ for all $x$ are real.

iii) Deduce from (i) and (ii) that $f(x) = \sin x$ for all $x$ are real.

Comment: Differentiate the left hand side in i) and ii).

Comment: For (i) after i differentiate the LHS I got zero. So how do I conclude that it is 1 ?

Comment: If the derivative of a differentiable function is $0$, the function is constant. Plug in the known values for $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$\left(f(x)\sin x+f'(x)\cos x\right)=f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x+f''(x)\cos x-f'(x)\sin x=$$

$$=\cos x\left[f(x)+f''(x)\right]=0\implies \ldots$$

And remember: if a function is constant then you can take **any** value for the free variable to find out what that constant is...

Comment: Thank you how about part iii ?

Comment: Is Taylor Theorem applicable for this case?

Comment: I've no the slightest idea why, where, how and what for would anyone want to apply Taylor's Theorem in this case...Explain yourself.

Comment: @Fred, for (iii) multiply (i) by $\;\sin x\,$ and (ii) by...and then...

Answer (score 0):

(iii) from part (ii), you have f(x)cosx = f′(x)sinx. so you can express f'(x) in terms of f(x), cos x and sin x. Substitute this expression of f'(x) into the result of part (i) you will get the answer